# Vim: How to permanently allow auto indent only on manual linebreak

Tags: vim

Vim has a tendency to automagically mess with the indentations in the line I'm currently working on, as well as placing linebreaks. I want it to do an automatic indentation when I manually make a linebreak (i.e. physically hitting the Enter key), but not in any other case, I don't want it to make any linebreaks itself either, and I want these settings  to be permanent.

Comment: What does `:set textwidth?` show?

Comment: it says textwidth=132

Comment: Can we have a complete list of requirements and an idea of what you actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

The `textwidth` option controls the number of characters after which a line break will be inserted, see `:h textwidth`.

To turn off the insertion of line breaks while editing, the following lines should be added to `.vimrc`:

```
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
set formatexpr=
```

Information on the options can be obtained by the usual `:h` command.

Note that these options are set globally but may be overridden e.g. by a filetype plugin. If the problem persists, see `:h ftplugin`.

Another question is where `:set textwidth=132` originates from. This may be due to an earlier misconfiguration or set from any plugin.